# Creating multiple list items in list element with a loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop

Trying to have really simple clean vanilla JS code here. This loop seems to only run once. No errors in console. Not sure what to do in order to fix.

```js
'use strict';
function start(){
  var d = document, 
      main = d.getElementsByTagName('main')[ 0 ],
      ul = d.createElement( 'ul' ),
      li = d.createElement( 'li' ),
      textContent = d.createTextNode( 'Item ' ),
      i;
  
  main.appendChild( ul );
  li.appendChild( textContent );
  
  for( i = 0; i <= 9; i = i + 1 ){
    ul.appendChild( li );
  }
}
start();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <main>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

What seems to be happening is `appendChild` is just appending that one list element over and over again just replacing itself. I have seen some examples like this where they use the `new` keyword but I have read articles that advise against. Any idea the best way to get 10 list items in the `ul` element from this loop?

Comment: You have to create a brand new `li` element every time or you have to clone it. Because every time you are re-appending the same element (cutting it out and appending it).

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I figured this might be the case. Not quite sure how to proceed. Will I have to use the `new` keyword?

Comment: you need to create it each time just like you did at the begining with d.createElement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
'use strict';
function start(){
  var d = document, 
      main = d.getElementsByTagName('main')[ 0 ],
      ul = d.createElement( 'ul' ),
      i;
  
  main.appendChild( ul );
  
  
  for( i = 0; i <= 9; i = i + 1 ){
    var li = d.createElement( 'li' );               // create a new li element
    li.textContent = "Item " + (i+1);               // .textContent is mush shorter than creating a textNode
    ul.appendChild( li );                           // every time append a new item
  }
}
start();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <main>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Every time `var li` is evaluated, the reference to the old li element is destroyed and a new element is created (whom reference is stored in the variable `li`). he destruction of the reference doesn't mean that the li element itself is destroyed, it just mean that the variable `li` is recreated with a reference to a new li element, the old element is still in DOM.